# What should I do with the redundant state of a ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I gotta a companion script for a serviceworker and I'm trialling right now.

The script works like so:

```
((n, d) => {

  if (!(n.serviceWorker && (typeof Cache !== 'undefined' && Cache.prototype.addAll))) return; 

  n.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js', { scope: './book/' })
    .then(function(reg) {

        if (!n.serviceWorker.controller) return;

        reg.onupdatefound = () => {

          let installingWorker = reg.installing;

          installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
            switch (installingWorker.state) {
              case 'installed':
                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                  updateReady(reg.waiting);

                } else {
                  // This is the initial serviceworker…
                  console.log('May be skipwaiting here?');
                }
                break;

              case 'waiting':
                updateReady(reg.waiting);
                break;

              case 'redundant':
                // Something went wrong?
                console.log('[Companion] new SW could not install…')
                break;
            }
          };
        };
    }).catch((err) => {
      //console.log('[Companion] Something went wrong…', err);
    });

    function updateReady(worker) {
        d.getElementById('swNotifier').classList.remove('hidden');

        λ('refreshServiceWorkerButton').on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          worker.postMessage({ 'refreshServiceWorker': true } );
        });

        λ('cancelRefresh').on('click', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          d.getElementById('swNotifier').classList.add('hidden');
        });

    }

    function λ(selector) {

      let self = {};

      self.selector = selector;

      self.element = d.getElementById(self.selector);

      self.on = function(type, callback) {
        self.element['on' + type] = callback;
      };

      return self;
    }

    let refreshing;

    n.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function() {
      if (refreshing) return;
      window.location.reload();
      refreshing = true;
    });    


})(navigator, document);
```

I'm a bit overwhelmed right now by the enormity of the service workers api and unable to "see" what one would do with `reg.installing` returning a `redundant` state?

Apologies if this seems like a dumb question but I'm new to serviceworkers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the definition here https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#service-worker-state-attribute I am guessing just print a log in case it comes up in debugging otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 8):

It's kinda difficult to work out what your intent is here so I'll try and answer the question generally.

A service worker will become redundant if it fails to install or if it's superseded by a newer service worker.

What you do when this happens is up to you. What do you want to do in these cases?

Comment: What are the choices? As @jason livesay suggested I don't see there's much to do with a redundant worker other than console.logging it.

Comment: You might want to notify the user, or retry updating/registering sometime later.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove any UI prompts you created that ask the user to do *something* in order to activate the latest service worker. And be patient a little longer.

You have 3 service workers, as you can see on the [registration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration):

1. `active`: the one that is running
2. `waiting`: the one that was downloaded, and is ready to become `active`
3. `installing`: the one that we just found, being downloaded, after which it becomes `waiting`

When a service worker reaches #2, you may display a prompt to the user about the new version of the app being just a click away. Let's say they don't act on it.

Then you publish a new version. Your app detects the new version, and starts to download it. At this point, you have 3 service workers. The one at #2 changes to `redundant`. The one at #3 is not ready yet. You should remove that prompt.

Once #3 is downloaded, it takes the place of #2, and you can show that prompt again.

Answer (score 1):

Write catch function to see the error. It could be SSL issue.

```
/* In main.js */
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
    .then(function(registration) {
        console.log("Service Worker Registered", registration);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Service Worker Failed to Register", err);
    })
}
```